# Co-coercivity of gradient

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $f$ is convex with $dom$ $f$ $= R^{n}$ and $g(x) = x^{T}x - f(x)$ is convex,

how to prove the Co-coercivity of gradient?

$$(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{T}(x - y) \geq 1/L \parallel \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \parallel ^{2}_{2}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the answer in [ucla lecture](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf) Page 1-16.

Comment: More precisely, see pdf page $16$ for the statement and pdf page $17$ for the proof.